# Print text on label printer from android using Direct Protocol Printer Language (Honeywell)

Tags: android, printing, sdk

I am trying to develop an app which will use label printer (Honeywell PC 42T) as its main printer.
This particular printer doesn't have specific SDK for android so i have to bypass and directly send command to this printer using its language, which is Direct Protocol. According to sample code [here](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-print-on-Honeywell-mobile-printers-using-Java) and [here](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/Sample-DP-Direct-Protocol-Layout), i wrote a piece of code to print on it.

This is the code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                try
                {
                    Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.199.106", 9100);
                    PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                    oStream.println("PP 25,35"); // Command to set print starting position
                    oStream.println("PT This is a test"); // Command to set text
                    oStream.println("PF"); // Command to feed the label after printing
                    oStream.println("PRINT KEY OFF"); // Command to finish printing
                    oStream.close();
                    sock.close();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            thread.start();
```

This code will feed the label but not printing on it.
Has anyone had some experience with this before? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with you, maybe you want try ZPL, as a mention in description of PC42t that this printer compatible with ZPL

> Integration into existing and new printing environments is particularly fast, thanks to numerous emulations like Direct Protocol (DP), ZSim (ZPL-II), ESim (EPL), especially since the printer languages are automatically identified and without any pre-settings.

You could take a look at this Java library (credit goes to the creator w3blogfr): https://github.com/w3blogfr/zebra-zpl

I already used this library and working properly.